# solving recurrence examples of form T(n-i) + f(n)

Tags: math, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence

I've been working on a problem set for a bit now and I seem to have gotten the master method down for recurrence examples. However, I find myself having difficulties with other methods (recurrence trees, substitution). here is the question I am stuck on: T(n) = T(n-2) + n^2 Is there a pattern as follows? n^2 + T(n-2) + T(n-4) +... where it goes until there is no more n left. so around n/2 times and would that mean that n^2 + (n-2)^2 + (n-i) ^2 so the asymptotic bound would be theta(n^2)??

I am honestly taking a shot in the dark here, so I was hoping someone could help guide me in how to approach these questions. perhaps not a direct answer to the question but a hint as to where I should begin would be best.

Comment: @MrE I'm having trouble with T(n-2) I can do the ones that satisfy the requirements for Master method such as T(n/2) + F(n)

Comment: I'm looking at the sum of squares right now, Sum(from k=0 ... n) k^2 = (n(n+1)(2n+1))/6. which I can see how that boils down to O(n^3). Yet I don't see how you concluded that it came down to sum of squares? (sorry this area of study isnot my forte) do you just ignore the constants (the subtractions such as -2 , -4, -i) ? and get sum(k=1...n/2) k^2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, the result is going to be n^2 + (n-2)^2 + (n-4)^2 + ...

Intuitively you can feel that because there are a lot (n/2) elements in the sum, it's going to be more than O(n^2) - the same way as 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n is more than O(n).

One way to prove it is that you can approximate the sum with half of the sum of all the square numbers, for which there is a [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number). So it's Theta(n^3).

Comment: ah yes I read some of that page and now I think I see it. so it is approximating the sum with half of the sum of all square numbers because we have n^2 + (n-2)^2 + (n-4)^2... rather than n^2 + (N-1)^2... and thats where you get the SS formula to get theta(n^3).

Comment: yes, the sum of squares of evens (eg: 4^2+2^2) is bigger than the one for odds (3^2+1^2), but if you add one more odd (5^2) to the equation that sum is going to be bigger. Because the total sum is theta(n^3), getting half of the sum is a good enough approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to massage the sum into the result

```
n^2 + (n-2)^2 + ... + (n -2i) + ...

= {just writing in a different way}

(2n/2) + (2n/2 - 2)^2 + ... + (2n/2 -2i)^2 + ...

= {write m = n/2}

(2m)^2 + (2m-2)^2 + ... (2m - 2i)^2 + ...

= 4 ( m^2 + (m-1)^2 + ... (m-i)^2 ...)

= 4 ( sum (k^2) from k=1 to m)

= 4 ( sum (k^2) from k=1 to n/2)

= (n^3 + 3n^2 + 2n)/6
```

using the [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number)